# Graphviz PDF Output Size

Tags: graphviz

I need to plot a diagram with graphviz including a lot of nodes which all have one connection to a main-node.

graphviz plot this as a diagram with a huge width.

Is there a possibility to set the size of pdf output witdh?

Answer (score 2):

You can give height and width in your code

**For Example**

```
import graphviz as gv
g2 = gv.Digraph(format='pdf')
g2.attr(width="900pt", height="1800pt",fixedsize='true')
```